# c# Count number of double break lines that is before a certain string

Tags: c#, regex

I have a string like this

```
var text = "Hello\\n\\nMr Foo rrr\\n\\nHello\n\nMr Bar rrr\\n\\n"`
```

and, I'm trying to count the occurrences of `"\\n\\n"` that is before  each name ex; number of `"\\n\\n"` before Foo is 2 and for Bar it's 4

I tried using this code but it does not get the expected results

```
var r = new Regex("(\\\\n)");
var index = text.IndexOf(m.Value, StringComparison.CurrentCulture);
var matchesBreakLines = r.Matches(text.Substring(0, index)).Count;
```

Comment: You do know that a string like "yes\\no" contains no line break or line end characters, right? It is the string "yes" followed by a single backslash followed by "no". Your Regex is interesting, it consists of a pair of backslashes, followed by "n". Btw, do you know that on Windows, the line end sequence is "\r\n" (a <CR> followed by a <LF>). You _may_ also want to look at the `Multiline` property of the ` Regex` class

Answer (score 0):

I solved using the following solution:

```
private static int GetBreakLineCount(string text, int length)
    {
        var substr = text.Substring(0, length);
        var r = new Regex("(\\\\n)");
        return r.Matches(substr).Count;
    }
```